# how to hide labels in python until a button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm building a flashcard app and want a label to pop up when the user gets the answer correct. I was wondering how to make it so that both labels are hidden until one of the buttons is pressed and then only one would show up(and preferably disappear when the next button is pressed). My code so far is below.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from random import randint
import random


root = Tk()
root.title('Chemistry Flashcards')
root.geometry("500x500")

def balancing():
    hide_all_frames()
    balancing_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)




    global show_balancing
    show_balancing = Label(balancing_frame)
    show_balancing.pack(pady=15)

    global balancing_list
    balancing_list = ['balanced1', 'balanced2', 'balanced3', 'balanced4', 'balanced5', 'unbalanced1', 'unbalanced2', 'unbalanced3', 'unbalanced4', 'unbalanced5']

    global balanced_list
    balanced_list = balancing_list[:5]


    global unbalanced_list
    unbalanced_list = balancing_list[5:10]


    global rando_image
    rando_image = random.choice(balancing_list)

    global balancing_image
    balancing1 = "C:/Users/Kisitu/Desktop/project/balancing/" + rando_image + ".png"
    balancing_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(balancing1))
    show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image)



    global balanced_button
    balanced_button = Button(balancing_frame, text = 'balanced', command = balancing_answer).pack()

    global unbalanced_button
    unbalanced_button = Button(balancing_frame, text = 'unbalanced', command = balancing_answer).pack()

    global balanced_label
    balanced_label = Label(balancing_frame, text='It was balanced', font=("Helvetica",18), bg='#B3FDFF')
    balanced_label.pack(pady=15)

    global unbalanced_label
    unbalanced_label = Label(balancing_frame, text='It was unbalanced', font=("Helvetica",18), bg='#B3FDFF')
    unbalanced_label.pack(pady=15)






    balancing()



def hide_all_frames():

    for widget in balancing_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    balancing_frame.pack_forget()


balancing_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, )


my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu, bg='#B7F7BB')

#menu options(elements and compound)
lesson_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Lesson", menu=lesson_menu)
lesson_menu.add_command(label="balancing", command=balancing)
lesson_menu.add_separator()
lesson_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)


'''
end
'''
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  functions to both buttons

```
def balancing_answer(): #this will make the label to show and hide
    balanced_label.pack(pady=15)
    unbalanced_label.pack_forget()

def unbalancing_answer(): #this will make the label to show and hide
    balanced_label.pack_forget()
    unbalanced_label.pack(pady=15)



global balanced_button
balanced_button = Button(balancing_frame, text = 'balanced', command = balancing_answer).pack()

global unbalanced_button
unbalanced_button = Button(balancing_frame, text = 'unbalanced', command = unbalancing_answer).pack() # change the command to unbalancing_answer

global balanced_label
    balanced_label = Label(balancing_frame, text='It was balanced', font=("Helvetica",18), bg='#B3FDFF')


global unbalanced_label
    unbalanced_label = Label(balancing_frame, text='It was unbalanced', font=("Helvetica",18), bg='#B3FDFF')

#    balancing()  # no need for this
```

If I get your question correctly; this will make the labels to pop up and disappear.

Comment: yeah thanks it worked but another problem appeared. the purpose of the balancing() at the bottom was to refresh the page so that a new random image would show up but how would i do that if i don't use the balancing()?

Comment: If the global balancing image part Is working. Then attach the 
        show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image) to each of the function balancing_answer() and unbalancing_answer(). At each click a new image will appear at random. I hope this helped

Comment: it doesnt make a new image appear. maybe I'm not understanding right but i placed them in the functions balancing_answer and unbalancing_answer so they look like this  ```def balancing_answer(): #this will make the label to show and hide
    balanced_label.pack(pady=15)
    unbalanced_label.pack_forget()
    show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image)

def unbalancing_answer(): #this will make the label to show and hide
    balanced_label.pack_forget()
    unbalanced_label.pack(pady=15)
    show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image)```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from random import randint
import random
root = Tk()
root.title('Chemistry Flashcards')
root.geometry("500x500")


def balancing_answer():
    balancing_frame.pack()
    balanced_label.pack(pady=15)
    unbalanced_label.pack_forget()
    show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image)


def unbalancing_answer():
    balancing_frame.pack_forget()
    balanced_label.pack_forget()
    unbalanced_label.pack(pady=15)
    show_balancing.config(image=balancing_image)


#two frames-unbalancing frame and balancing frame
balancing_frame = Frame(root)
unbalancing_frame=Frame(root)

#this is the show balancing frame
show_balancing = Label(balancing_frame)
show_balancing.pack()

#only one image is specified. there can be no random images.but the image will flash up at a click and disappear at another click
img = Image.open('p.jpg').convert("RGBA")
w, h = img.size
left = w/5
right = 3*w/5
upper = h/5
lower = 3*h/5
img2 = img.crop([ left, upper, right, lower]) #this part is used to crop the image. you can choose to ignore
balancing_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)



#two buttons to click

balanced_button = Button(unbalancing_frame,       text = 'balanced', command = balancing_answer).pack()
unbalanced_button = Button(unbalancing_frame, text = 'unbalanced', command = unbalancing_answer).pack()



#the two labels balanced and unbalanced
balanced_label = Label(balancing_frame, text="it was balanced", font=("Helvetica",9), bg='#B3FDFF')
unbalanced_label = Label(unbalancing_frame, text='It was unbalanced', font=("Helvetica",9), bg='#B3FDFF')


#when the user click balancing.. a new frame appear
def balancing():
    unbalancing_frame.pack()


#========the menu=========

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu, bg='#B7F7BB')
#menu options(elements and compound)
lesson_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Lesson", menu=lesson_menu)
lesson_menu.add_command(label="balancing", command=balancing)
lesson_menu.add_separator()
lesson_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try that and see if It correspond with what you want. You can leave your comments